# Display a Linear Layout programmatically in a loop

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello everyone please i need help. I'm a biginner in Android programming so since i was trying to solve this problem it took me all my days that why i want you to help me please. I'm trying to display a Linear layout according to the loop condition but the issue is that when i'm doing that it's just displaying the last one and i'm not able to see others when it's displaying. Here are my codes

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    sv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    sv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    sv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
    LinearLayout ll = null;
    for (int i=0; i < 2; i++){
        try {

            //Here iam defining the LinearLayout
            ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setId(i);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            ll.setLayoutParams(params);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            ll.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.circle_view));

            //Here iam defining the RelativeLayout
            RelativeLayout Rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            Rl.setLayoutParams(param);

            //Defining a layout params for widgets
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams image = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 90);
            image.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);
            //Creating widgets
            ImageView im = new ImageView(this);
            im.setImageResource(R.mipmap.airtel);
            im.setId(R.id.image1);
            im.setLayoutParams(image);
            //----------------
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams txtone = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            txtone.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.image1);
            txtone.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 45);

            TextView txtVone = new TextView(this);
            txtVone.setText("ArkaL"+i);
            //txtVone.setTextSize(R.dimen.MainTextSize);
            txtVone.setTextSize(15);
            txtVone.setTypeface(txtVone.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
            txtVone.setLayoutParams(txtone);

            //------------------------------------------------
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams txttwo = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            txttwo.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.image1);
            txttwo.setMargins(0, 45, 0, 0);
            TextView txtVtwo = new TextView(this);
            txtVtwo.setText("République Démocratique du Congo");
            txtVtwo.setTypeface(txtVtwo.getTypeface(), Typeface.SERIF.getStyle());
            txtVtwo.setTextSize(10);
            txtVtwo.setLayoutParams(txttwo);

            Rl.addView(im);
            Rl.addView(txtVone);
            Rl.addView(txtVtwo);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams recycler = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            RecyclerView rv = new RecyclerView(this);
            rv.setLayoutParams(recycler);
            ll.addView(Rl);
            ll.addView(rv);

        }catch (Exception e){

        }

    }
    //Here for assigning Linear to ScrollView
    sv.addView(ll);
    this.setContentView(sv);
```

Please help me.

Comment: try   ```ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is that you created one `LinearLayout` and changed it in a loop and then added it to a `ScrollView` so at the end you will have just one LinearLayout. as you may know an ScrollView should have just one View as a child view so you should add a LinearLayout for a ScrollView and add as many LinearLayout as you want to the primary LinearLayout. your code can be like this:

```
LinearLayout llMain = new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
llMain.setLayoutParams(params2);
llMain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
sv.addView(llMain);
LinearLayout ll = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
 try {

  //Here iam defining the LinearLayout
  ll = new LinearLayout(this);
  ll.setId(i);
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  ll.setLayoutParams(params);
  ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
  ...
  llMain.addView(ll);
 } catch (Exception e) {
  ...
```

note that the Height of primary linearlayour should wrap its content;